# Phalcon - Create an new file instance

Tags: php, phalcon

In phalcon you can get uploaded file with this piece of code

```
//Check if the user has uploaded files
if ($this->request->hasFiles() == true) {
    //Print the real file names and their sizes
    foreach ($this->request->getUploadedFiles() as $file){
        echo $file->getName(), " ", $file->getSize(), "\n";
    }
}
```

each $file is an Phalcon\Http\Request\File instance.

But what if I want to create an file instance from an existing file on the server, how can I do that?

What I tried is this:

```
new Phalcon\Http\Request\File(array($fileDir));
```

But it returns an instance with empty properties.

any help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation of that class](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Http_Request_File.html) I think the constructor does not expect an array. So just leave out the `array( )` that you are passing to the constructor and you should be fine. Disclaimer: I did not check out the code and rely on the documentation being proper here.

Code example:

```
new Phalcon\Http\Request\File($fileDir);
```

Comment: P.S.: I find it quite weird though to use a file of a "Phalcon\Http\Request" namespace for an file that is already stored, as it looks like this is only handling files that have to do with HTTP requests. However, I also do not see any other class in their API docs that seems to be more of an match. Just for something to think about.

Comment: Thank you for your time :)
According to this (https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/blob/master/ide/2.0.9/Phalcon/http/request/File.php) (and according to my error message) It accepts only an array. I think an array of file locations. Which is not logic because an file instance is 1 instance of an file not multiple.

Comment: I could do it the dirty way and edit the $_FILES to add the information and then use the foreach loop in my question. But that is not nice and there must probably be an better solution

Comment: Interesting. Well I am probably not deep enough into phalcon. I do not even understand how this "Class" is supposed to work at all, given that it has no implementation in its methods. I am guessing there is some magic to fill the properties or something like that. Sorry that I can not help you more (and that I answered prematurely)

Comment: No problem. It is an reflection of what the actual code is since the source code is written in C++ and loaded as an plugin to apache2 so no one could look in the source code only to the reflections of it.

Comment: As you can see https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/http/request/file.zep#L78  the constructor expect an array  and throws exception if it isn't array

Answer (score 0):

> But what if I want to create an file instance from an existing file on the server, how can I do that?

This class is designed to work with `$_FILES` superglobal, so as for me you are using wrong tool. I would create your own wrapper for using files that are already on server, or go for [SplFileObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php).

Anyway, how should parameter array look like you may be able to anderstand from [here](https://api.phalconphp.com/source/Phalcon/Http/Request/File.html) starting at line 74+ and it pretty reflects `$_FILES` structure.